# Why doesn't Isotope use 3d transforms for performance?

Tags: css, css-transitions, masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope ([isotope.metafizzy.co](http://isotope.metafizzy.co)) with a Masonry Horizontal layout. Example:
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/oCiAD

It works just fine, but I'm curious as to why the library sets the left/right and top/bottom properties instead of using transforms. It's my understanding that using 3D such as

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

or

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

will force the element onto another layer, triggering GPU rendering and better performance. I realize this is probably done intentionally, but I'm not clear as to why.

Have browsers improved and is this no longer necessary? If not, is there a way to enable 3d transforms in Isotope?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066628/how-to-use-jquery-isotope-in-right-to-left

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the reasons could be that Webkit treats 3d transformed elements as textures instead of vectors in order to provide hardware 3d acceleration which could cause a blurry text or anti-aliasing issues.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/ccw7vvvg/

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 100px, 0px);
```